# TableViewController content not displaying content (reloadData)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I'm using a **TableViewController** to show some "entries" from my database and I'm trying to use `[self.tableView reloadData];` in order to reload the Table when the content is loaded, but it's not working because the content is only displayed if I touch the screen up or down, if I leave it without touching is not showing anything.

I think I have put the **[self.tableView reloadData];** in the correct position because for some reason is not showing until I move the screen with my finger.

**Why is this happening and what can I do to reload automatically my tableview?**

***CarTableViewController.m:***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchJson];
}
```

***And that's my fetchJson:***

```
-(void)fetchJson {

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.carMakes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.likes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.comments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        @try
        {
            NSError *error;
            [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
            _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                         JSONObjectWithData:data
                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                         error:&error];

            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                [_carImages addObject:imagen];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* user = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"user"];
                [_carMakes addObject:user];

                NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString* date = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"date"];
                [_carModels addObject:date];
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException * e)
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        }
        @finally
        {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your: numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath methods.

Comment: Have you tried ensuring that `self.tableView reloadData` is running on the main thread

Comment: Edited with more code @OlegSobolev.

Comment: How can I see if that self.tableView.reloadData is working? Thanks @Flexicoder

Comment: change it to this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self.tableView reloadData] });`

Comment: @Lock_85_Dr: check 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' whether calling or not while reload tableView. ( add a break point and check).

Comment: This looks like a very similar question by a "different" user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818394/segue-index-0-beyond-bounds-for-empty-array/26818448#26818448

Comment: I think, first of all you do not need try, catch and finally statement because you are using priority queues. Your code look fines. I think that you should load data before  your view appears (tableview) or initialize your table with some default data to show.

Comment: Thanks @user3833571 so I will have to put the "reloadData" before my fetchJson call? Thanks.

Comment: Try to put [self fetchJson]; in viewWillAppear instead viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had that problem very often when I was starting to develop iOS apps.

The problem is, that you don't run the *reloadData* on the main thread, which is responsible for the UI. In fact, if you run this method (not in the main thread), the data of your tableView is actually reloaded, but not shown to the user. So if you start scrolling the tableView, the main thread "draws" your user interface and therefore the data is shown. 
So you have to run *reloadData* on the main thread.

So take out the

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and add these lines of code after your data is successfully fetched from your database (and the values are stored in your dictionaries/arrays):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

I think you can even put that code inside your *@finally* block. The main *main_queue* contains the tasks that run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks @beeef. I'm going to try that, I hope it works ;) Regards.